# Cannot run command with xvfb-run in cron job

Tags: linux, cron

I need to run a command headless that contains some GUI elements that aren't actually manifested. If I perform a login via ssh (with no X forwarding) the following command works:

/usr/bin/xvfb-run -a -e /tmp/xvfp.log /usr/local/bin/sclang /home/pi/nonpinned_hdls.scd

I would like to run this command on startup and entered the following line in a crontab:

@reboot /usr/bin/xvfb-run -a -e /tmp/xvfp.log /usr/local/bin/sclang /home/pi/nonpinned_hdls.scd

This does not work on reboot. However I can confirm that sclang has been called. eg. ps -ef | grep sclang:

pi       375   348  0 10:17 ?        00:00:00 /bin/sh -c /usr/bin/xvfb-run -a -e /tmp/xvfp.log /usr/local/bin/sclang /home/pi/nonpinned_hdls.scd

pi       376   375  0 10:17 ?        00:00:00 /bin/sh /usr/bin/xvfb-run -a -e /tmp/xvfp.log /usr/local/bin/sclang /home/pi/nonpinned_hdls.scd

pi       485   376  2 10:17 ?        00:00:06 /usr/local/bin/sclang /home/pi/nonpinned_hdls.scd

pi      1159   927  0 10:21 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto sclang

There is nothing written to /tmp/xvfp.log.

Any suggestions please? Thanks!

Comment: Did you put this in `root`'s crontab or your own? Are you sure you are using the right syntax?

Comment: I put in my own crontab. Other tests such as the following, do work:  @reboot echo "Testing cron" > /tmp/cront.txt

Comment: Also tried this in cron: @reboot xvfb-run --server-args='-screen 0, 1024x768x16' /usr/local/bin/sclang /home/pi/nonpinned_hdls.scd > /dev/null